# How to add JTree dynamically to a created JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtree

MY Jtree component is created within a actionperformed function. But I've already created a Jscrollpane in the constructor and added it to the JFrame.

Now within the actionperformed function, I tried to add the dynamically created JTree to the JScrollpane using

```
JScrollpaneobject.add(JtreeObject);
JScrollpaneobject.revalidate();
```

But I am unable to see the Jtree on the Jscrollpane.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

direct variant of the same:

```
 scroll.setViewportView(jTree)
```

Answer (score 3):

scroll.getViewport().add(jTree)

Comment: nitpicking (after all, it's Monday :-) technically correct - as the viewport's addImpl is overridden to allow only a single child. For clarity I would prefer the use of `viewport.setView(comp)`